# Layering Objects || Google Map & Nav Bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an interactive google map page but I'm having a bit of trouble layering the divs.

My html looks something like this

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
    <p class="logo"> Put a logo here later </p>
</div>
    <div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li> link 1 </li>
        <li> link 2 </li>
        <li> link 3 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Google Maps</h1>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <p> Put a footer down here later </p>
</div>
</div>
```

and the related css looks like this

```
#map{
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
left: 0px; top: 0px; 
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 0;
}
.nav{
background-color: #fff;
width: 120px;
height: 500px;
z-index: 100;
}
```

What happens at the moment is the map takes the entire page (intentional) but I want the nav bar to float on top somehow. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `position:absolute;` to your `.nav`

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/xanen/2/edit)**

that was to answer your last question (*float nav bar on top of map somehow*).

---

If you want everything to be over the map... do it this way:

```
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="everythingElse"><!--all other content--></div>
</body>
```

setting **#everythingElse** also to `position: absolute;`

Example: http://jsbin.com/xanen/3/edit